# Ajax POST working, but php document cannot get data variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

When I post something, the network tab of chrome shows that the post is going through with the correct variables, but on the php end, the POST global is empty, and the method on the page is GET for some reason. I hope I am not just missing something obvious, I spent like 4-5 hours troubleshooting. What is occuring, or is suppose to, is that when you type anything in the searchbox, an event listener in the js file triggers and POSTs the value of the search box to the php of the storepage.php. The search bar itself is actually on a seperate php file which makes a header for every html page, but the php that queries the database is in the storepage.php

Picture of network results from entering items into search (notice variable `searchInput` at bottom of image)
[image: Picture of network results from entering items into search (notice variable "searchInput" at bottom of image)]

This is where the Ajax POST happens: searchItUp.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("Document Ready. Listening for search bar key presses...");
    $('.SearchBar').keyup(function() {     
        console.log("Key pressed.");
        var searchBoxValue = document.getElementById('superSearcher').value;
        console.log("Current searchbox value: " + searchBoxValue);
        jQuery.ajax({
            method: "post",
            url: "storepage.php",
            data: {searchInput: searchBoxValue},
            datatype: "text",

            success: function () {
                console.log("Ajax functioning properly...");
                $('.content').load(document.URL +  ' .content>*');
            },
            error: function() { 
                console.log("Ajax NOT functioning properly...");
            }
        });
    });
 });
```

Next is the section of the php document (storepage.php) where the javascript file is included, and the POST is directed to.

```php
if (isset($_POST["searchInput"]) && !empty($_POST["searchInput"])) {
        echo "searchInput is set...  ";    
    } else {  
        echo "searchInput is not set...  ";
    }
    echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    $searchInput = $_POST['searchInput'];
    if ($searchInput=="") {
                // query all game information based on text in the search bar
                $query = "SELECT ProductID,ImgID,Image,GameName,ESRB_ID,ESRB_Img,Rating,ReleaseDate,Description,Tags,Price,PlatformID,PlatformName 
                    FROM PRODUCTS 
                    JOIN PRODUCT_IMAGES USING (ImgID) 
                    JOIN GAME_INFO USING (GameID) 
                    JOIN PLATFORMS USING (PlatformID)
                    JOIN ESRB USING (ESRB_ID)";
                $statement = $db->prepare($query);
                $statement->execute();
                $GameList = $statement->fetchAll();
                $statement->closeCursor();
                echo "<script>console.log( 'Game database queried WITHOUT search' );</script>";
            }
            else {
                // query all game information if search is empty
                $query = "SELECT ProductID,ImgID,Image,GameName,ESRB_ID,ESRB_Img,Rating,ReleaseDate,Description,Tags,Price,PlatformID,PlatformName 
                        FROM PRODUCTS 
                        JOIN PRODUCT_IMAGES USING (ImgID) 
                        JOIN GAME_INFO USING (GameID) 
                        JOIN PLATFORMS USING (PlatformID)
                        JOIN ESRB USING (ESRB_ID)
                        WHERE GameName LIKE '%$searchInput%'";
                $statement = $db->prepare($query);
                $statement->execute();
                $GameList = $statement->fetchAll();
                $statement->closeCursor();
                echo "<script>console.log( 'Game database queried WITH search' );</script>";
            }
```

I have tried everything I could find online, and I have probably looked at all relevant stackoverflow, and other, posts, but I can't figure it out for the life of me.

Comment: you don't need to use both `isset` and `!empty`. `empty()` automatically checks `isset`.[

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're invoking the script twice. First with `$.ajax`, where you're sending the search parameter.

Then in the `success:` function, you invoke it again using `$('.content').load`. This sends a `GET` request without the search parameter. So it doesn't show the result of the search in `.content`.

The AJAX request should return whatever you want to show. Then you can do:

```
success: function(response) {
    $(".content").html(response);
}
```

Another option is to pass the parameter when calling `.load`. That changes it to a `POST` request:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("Document Ready. Listening for search bar key presses...");
  $('.SearchBar').keyup(function() {
    console.log("Key pressed.");
    var searchBoxValue = document.getElementById('superSearcher').value;
    console.log("Current searchbox value: " + searchBoxValue);
    $('.content').load(document.URL + ' .content>*', {
      searchInput: searchBoxValue
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Wow this is great, thanks! The only other problem I have now is, instead of just updating that one div (.content), it recreates the entire webpage within the div element. (Edit: Can I edit the url in the ajax post to specify just the div with .content tagged onto it?)

Comment: The AJAX script shouldn't print the entire page, it should just print what you need.

Comment: You could just use `.load()` instead of `$.ajax`, and it will extract the portion of the page you want.